# Finding minimum value of 2d numpy array based on second value of row

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I have a NumPy array similar to as shown below and I want to find the minimum element based on the second item of the row. I can achieve this using the sorted function, is there a built-in NumPy function to achieve the same (probably the one-liner function)?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,20], [2,3], [3,3], [4,3], [5,4],[1,2], [2,3], [3,3], [4,3], [5,4],[1,2], [2,3], [3,3], [4,3], [5,4], [1,2], [2,3], [3,3], [4,3], [5,4], [1,2], [2,3]])

min_ = sorted(a, key=lambda row: row[1])[0]
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Does this work? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmin.html#numpy-nanmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also have it like

```
a[np.argmin(a[:, 1])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `argsort`:

```
>>> a[a[:, 1].argsort()][0]
array([1, 2])
```

Comment: np.sort(a, axis=0)  gives [[ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  3],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 3,  3],
       [ 3,  3],
       [ 3,  3],
       [ 3,  3],
       [ 4,  3],
       [ 4,  3],
       [ 4,  3],
       [ 4,  4],
       [ 5,  4],
       [ 5,  4],
       [ 5,  4],
       [ 5, 20]]. Looks like it doesn't preserve the order.

Comment: My point is. Your solution just works for just this example. Change a=np.array([[1,20], [2,3], [3,3], [4,3], [5,1],[1,2], [2,3], [3,3], [4,3], [5,4],[1,2], [2,3], [3,3], [4,3], [5,4], [1,2], [2,3], [3,3], [4,3], [5,4], [1,2], [2,3]]), which your  np.sort(a, axis=0)[0] gives [1, 1] which is not even in a, is it?

Comment: @stochasticlearner - Aah, I see what you mean. Apologies, edited

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.lexsort` to sort multiple axes like the below:

```
>>> a[np.lexsort((a[:,1], a[:,0]))][0]
array([ 1,  2])
```

In python, sorts are guaranteed to be stable. If you have a value similar to the other values in the second column, maybe you get the wrong answer.

[Ref](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts):

> Sort Stability and Complex Sorts
>
> > Sorts are guaranteed to be stable. That means that when multiple records have the same key, their original order is preserved.

```
>>> a = np.array([[2,1], [1,1]])
>>> a[np.argmin(a[:, 1])]
array([ 2,  1])

>>> a[a[:, 1].argsort()][0]
array([ 2,  1])

>>> a[np.lexsort((a[:,1], a[:,0]))][0]
array([ 1,  1])
```

Comment: since you are slicing twice, will it hurt the performance?

Comment: @stochasticlearner edited answer. It's better you consider the first column too.